# Regex to consider non-alphanumeric character other than $

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a text  :

```
Revenue: $12.9 billion
Regex=====>Revenue\W+(\$*\s*\d+\s*(\.\s*\d+)*)\s*billion
```

Now I want $12.9 in a specific group but by using \W+ it takes ": $" after revenue.
So I want to write such regex that it will consider all nonalphanumeric character except "$"

How can I do that???

Comment: Revenue.\s.\d*.\d*\s\w+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A character class like `[^\w$]` will match anything that is not a word character or `$`. Also, there's no need to have `\s*` twice together, or to have it appear after `\W+` (or `[^\w$]+`) because the preceding character class will swallow up any whitespace characters anyway:

```
Revenue[^\w$]+(\d+\s*(\.\s*\d+))\s*billion
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Revenue[^\w$]+(.\s*\d+\s*(\.\s*\d+))\s*billion
```

use this,

the `.` will match the unmatched `$`

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/aQ8qP7

`$12.9` is captured in the first group